# What does it mean when malloc() or free() gives you a segmentation fault?

Tags: c, malloc, free

I am currently using `dlmalloc()` to see how much faster it can be than the original libc `malloc()`.

However, running `free()` keeps giving me a segmentation fault...

Does anyone know some logical reasons why this could keep happening?

Comment: If you call `dlmalloc()`, you are pairing that with `dlfree()`, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A segfault inside the memory management functions almost always indicates that you've done something wrong (like overwriting memory beyond the valid bounds) *before* the call that actually segfaults.

Running your code under [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) may help you determine the real source of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I would be looking first into memory corruption issues. For example, if you allocate `N` bytes and then write to `N+100` of them, you're very likely to corrupt the memory arena.

That's because many implementations keep their housekeeping information (block sizes, list pointers and so on) in-line (between the actual data areas).

Another possibility would be double freeing of blocks which may cause problems if that memory has since been used for some other allocation (especially if your address is now in the *middle* of a data area rather than at the beginning).

First things first, make sure you're following the rules. Any thing else is undefined behaviour and all bets are off.

You may also want to post the source code for the problem you're having so we can examine it. If you do this, try to reduce it to the smallest example that exhibits the problem. Only the most *dedicated* SOer <sup>(a)</sup> will want to look over some 10,000-line behemoth to find your issue .

---

<sup><sup>(a) And I'm certainly not that dedicated :-)</sup></sup>